# Get random image from server javascript / phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am using phaser game maker and I want to select a random image from my assets folder to display on screen. See below. '?' should equal the random image on the server.

```
    preload: function() { 

    var randImage = 'assets/' ?;
    game.load.image('rand', 'assets/' + randImage + '.png');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Phaser, but in general, you will probably need to place a list of all image filenames in the assets folder in the script and then execute roughly the following JavaScript:

```
var aImageFiles = ['SomeFileNames', 'Populate', 'This', 'Array', 'However', 'You', 'Want'];
var randImage = aImageFiles[Math.floor(Math.random()*aImageFiles.length)];
game.load.image('rand', 'assets/' + randImage + '.png');
```

Note: In this code, I have omitted `"assets/" +` from the `randImage` value assignment, because this would look for a file in the `assets/assets/`. I presume that is not the intended behavior, but I could be mistaken, so add that back in if need be.